# 404 JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, html, http-status-code-404

I have a strange problem.
Sometimes error 404 appears. But not always and thats the strange part..

I made a page with javaScript and at the end of the page iam changing images with this java script function

```js
 var backGround = ['img/wall1.jpg', 'img/wall2.jpg', 'img/wall3.jpg'];

       var header = document.getElementById('headerBlanco');    

       var i = 0;

    setInterval(function(){

        if(i !== backGround.length - 1){
            i++;
        }else{
            i = 0;
        }

        header.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + backGround[i] + ')';

    }, 6000);
```

It works like i wanted but sometimes the browser cant find a image and error 404 appears..

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**can somebody explain me why this can happen?**

This is the site where you can see it.
You need to click on the buttons to see it happen.

http://www.leerappel.nl

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"`

Comment: No thats not the error.. this is the error what i mean
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Next time please upload a complete code snippet.

Comment: For me everything works OK. Which browsers are you running? Can you upload a screenshot? Also, if you're using Google Chrome please check the Network tab for 404 response. Do you run it on a local web server or just on the leerappel.nl ?

Comment: And why did you set the height of headerBlanco to 0px?

Answer (score 0):

The error you have mentioned in your comment is caused by `header` being `null`. This means that `document.getElementById('headerBlanco')` yields `null`. That means that `headerBlanco` does not necessarily exist. Make sure that the element exists and your `url` is correct. Also, instead of

```
if(i !== backGround.length - 1){
    i++;
}else{
    i = 0;
}
```

you can do this:

```
i = (i + 1) % backGround.length;
```

EDIT:

It turns out I misunderstood the situation. I mistakenly believed that the first comment of the question was made by the author. Since the item has a value, the 404 can most probably be attributed to internet connection problems.

Comment: For me `document.getElementById('headerBlanco')` doesn't return `null`

Comment: Do you change the value of header somewhere else?

Comment: No. I just opened the site and ran `document.getElementById('headerBlanco')`

Comment: @SzymonMarczak can you console.log(header) just before the line where you had problems? Can you tell me what do you see just before the error message?

Comment: I have no problems - I use Google Chrome btw. It returns me the div.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak sorry, I misunderstood you. For some reason I thought you were the first commenter of your question.

Comment: My question? I didn't ask this question. I just commented to your answer to tell you how is it on my side :D The autor of the question is Barry B.